# nested if-statement not functioning properly

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-if

I have taken this from a program that checks for credit card validation. The code below is put inside another if-statement. Although the statement is true, it still outputs as it is false. Both `validation` and `lastDigit` are integers.

Here is my code:

```
if (validation == lastDigit){
 System.out.println("Check digit should be: " + validation);
 System.out.println("Check digit is: " + lastDigit);
 System.out.println("Number is valid.");
 System.out.println();
}
else {
 System.out.println("Check digit should be: " + validation);
 System.out.println("Check digit is: " + lastDigit);
 System.out.println("Number is not valid.");
 System.out.println();
 }
```

Here is my output:

```
Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): 5457623898234113
Check digit should be: 3
Check digit is: 3
Number is not valid.

Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): 5555555555554445
Check digit should be: 4
Check digit is: 5
Number is not valid.

Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit): 4012888888881881
Check digit should be: 1
Check digit is: 1
Number is not valid.

Enter a credit card number (enter a blank line to quit):
```

Even when the validation and `lastDigit` does equal to each other, like the first and the third input, it still executes as false.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You should mention bit more code where datatypes of the lastDigit and validation are also mentioned

Comment: Please include a [mre]. This might be your entire code, if it isn't too long.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data type is Integer, you should be comparing the two values with 'equals()' method.

```
if (validation.equals(lastDigit))
```

== compares references i.e. it checks if both validation and lastDigit point to the same object. Equals method checks whether the values of the two objects are the same.

Comment: This did not work, as it gave me an message that states, "Cannot invoke equals(char) on the primitive type int" .